# Magento 2 Shipping method available per customer

Tags: magento2, shipping-methods

normally on my checkout page there are 2 shipping method like this

[image: normal shipping method(image number 1)]

but sometimes when using login specific users, the shipping method just showed one
just like this

[image: shipping method just showed one(image number 2)]

the situation on image number 2 just happen on 2 users from total 216 users, so which is wrong whether my code or my data?
and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Each Shipping Carrier has a model extends `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier` implements `\Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface`

The method ::collectRates decide the shipping method could be available or not.

So this indicates that while you return `false` on this method, the method will not be available for selected.

See my new custom function to check customer group ::_checkUserPermission here if customerGroup not equal to 1(general) the shipping method would not be available.

```
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
            return false;
        }

        if(!$this->_checkUserPermission()) {
            return false;
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');

        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        if ($shippingPrice !== false) {
            $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true) {
                $shippingPrice = '0.00';
            }

            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException
     * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException
     */
    private function _checkUserPermission() {
        if ($quote = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()) {
            $customer = $quote->getCustomer();

            return $customer->getId() ? $customer->getGroupId() == 1 : false;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: after I check my code when call function collectRates there is no checking customer group

Comment: @YoanesRicard this is the customized code to check customer group, it was my code, it was my suggestion as you want to check per customer group, whether customer id or anything related to customer, you could take this as a sample.

Comment: after i debug there is something strange so response from model already show 2 shipping method, but the response from api estimate-shipping-method just showing 1 shipping method so how to debug this error?

Comment: you can check pic screenshoot of the response on here https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/315059/why-endpoints-estimate-shipping-method-just-return-one-shipping-method-even-tho